# Cannot access column in MySql table

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I can't access the `idRooms` column with the code below

```
try{
        Connection myConn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/HSM_schema","root","");
        Statement myStmt = myConn.createStatement();
        ResultSet myRs = myStmt.executeQuery("select * from Rooms");

        while(myRs.next()){
            System.out.println(myRs.getString("idRooms ")+", "+ myRs.getString("RoomType"));
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex){
    ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Here is my table:

[image]

When I run `myRs.getString("RoomType")` it works perfectly fine. Any thoughts?
Thanks you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to have an extra white space at the of if `idRooms`. Change `myRs.getString("idRooms ")` to `myRs.getString("idRooms")`.

Answer (score 2):

You have a redundant space after `idRooms`. Since you don't have a columns called `idRooms`, this will fail.
Just remove the redundant space, and you should be fine:

```
while(myRs.next()){
    System.out.println(myRs.getString("idRooms")+", "+ myRs.getString("RoomType"));
    // Here-----------------------------------^
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are having an space at end of the column name **"idRooms "** that must be the reason.

Since `idRooms` is a `int` column I suggest you to use `getInt` method instead of string method
so you can use

```
 System.out.println(myRs.getInt("idRooms")+", "+ myRs.getString("RoomType"));
```

or

```
System.out.println(myRs.getString(1)+", "+ myRs.getString(2)); // using coloumn index
```

or

```
 System.out.println(myRs.getInt(1)+", "+ myRs.getString(2));
```